# TYPO3 FAL Image in section of a DCE

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm in the process to migrate an old v7 TYPO3 installation to v11. But I struggle with a DCE content element which uses sections and within the section a relation to `sys_file`.

The old flexform code looks like this:

```xml
<config>
    <type>group</type>
    <internal_type>db</internal_type>
    <appearance>
        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
    </appearance>
    <allowed>sys_file</allowed>
    <size>1</size>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
    <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
</config>
```

When I try to migrate the flexform code to use FAL, I end up with this error message in the TYPO3 backend:

> #1458745468 UnexpectedValueException
> Invalid flex form data structure on field name "pi_flexform" with element "sliderImage" in section container "container_carousel": Nesting inline elements in flex form sections is not allowed.

The flexform I used is a preset from DCE:

```xml
<config>
    <type>inline</type>
    <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
    <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
    <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
    <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
    <foreign_match_fields>
        <fieldname>{$variable}</fieldname>
    </foreign_match_fields>
    <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
    <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
    <overrideChildTca>
        <columns>
            <uid_local>
                <config>
                    <appearance>
                        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                </config>
            </uid_local>
        </columns>
        <types type="array">
            <numIndex index="2">
                <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
            </numIndex>
        </types>
    </overrideChildTca>

    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>99</maxitems>

    <appearance>
        <useSortable>1</useSortable>
        <headerThumbnail>
            <field>uid_local</field>
            <width>45c</width>
            <height>45</height>
        </headerThumbnail>

        <enabledControls>
            <info>1</info>
            <dragdrop>1</dragdrop>
            <hide>1</hide>
            <new>0</new>
            <sort>0</sort>
            <delete>1</delete>
        </enabledControls>

        <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
    </appearance>

    <behaviour>
        <allowLanguageSynchronization>1</allowLanguageSynchronization>
    </behaviour>

    <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
    <dce_get_fal_objects>1</dce_get_fal_objects>
</config>
```

Is it even possible to have a FAL relation within a section item of a DCE?

Or are there any other ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: What I did was just replace it by an input field. Then the editor needs to just make sure the file name is correct. No need for difficult migrations then, I only moved all the pics from the upload folder to the fileadmin. Imo get rid of solutions like DCE which still puts stuf in XML in the DB. I think it was an aggresive decision with the TYPO3 updates to remove a TCA option to select a file without FAL.

Comment: Remember if you update the DCE config, you also need to clear the flexform field in the db else errors will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even possible to have a FAL relation within a section item of a
> DCE?

No. The problem seems to be having an ID for such relations.

> Or are there any other ideas how to solve my problem?

For some (few) cases having multiple fields could be a solution. E.g. for an image-slider having fields "Pic1", "Text1", ..., "Pic5", "Text5".

Or get rid of DCE and migrate to custom CEs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue using the  flex form by putting
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file']['ctrl']['hideTable'] = 0; in dce/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4BUj.png)